# How to downgrade JRE's version in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, java, package-management, jre

Currently I am having [JRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine#Execution_environment) 1.6.0_20. How do I downgrade it to JRE 1.6.0_17?

How can I downgrade?

I'm using [Ubuntu 10.04 LTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_10.04_LTS_.28Lucid_Lynx.29).

Comment: You do know there is a security issue relating to remote code execution with Java < 1.6.0_20 don't you?  Is there any reason you need that specific version such as missing features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you downgrade, you'll probably want to keep it that way (having the update manager ignore the newer version), [this list thread](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-users/2007-June/116572.html) and the [APT-HowTo](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-apt-get.en.html) seem to go through what's needed to do that.

Specifically check out [How to keep a mixed system](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-apt-get.en.html#s-default-version):

```
# apt-get install package=version
```

And [How to keep specific versions of packages installed (complex)](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-apt-get.en.html#s-pin), adding this to `/etc/apt/preferences`:

```
Package: <package>
Pin: <pin definition>
Pin-Priority: <pin's priority>
```

**Update**: To clarify some things: 1. Ubuntu 10.04 *does not* use Sun's JRE by default. Infact you need to [enable repositories to install it](http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/releasenotes/1004#Sun%20Java%20moved%20to%20the%20Partner%20repository).

As stated in my comments, just follow the above pattern:

```
apt-get install default-jre=1.6.0_17
```

Or for Sun's

```
apt-get install sun-java6-jre=1.6.0_17
```

But I doubt that will work, considering that the latest version of Sun's JRE is listed as 6.20.

Comment: Thanks Tim Lyte for your time , i am trying it by downloading rpm packages externally . will let u know if it fails.

Comment: RPMs are meant for ReadHat (Fedora/CentOS/Etc), not Ubuntu/Debian. Look for a .deb file if you're trying to downgrade with a downloaded package.

Comment: no it takes older version (newer version previously installed),
in my case it is java
can you specify how can i install java jre&jdk 1.6.0_17 by apt-get ?

Comment: It really depends on what package you're installing. For Ubuntu's default (in 10.04) it would be `apt-get install default-jre=1.6.0_17` Just follow the pattern given in my answer.

Comment: in ubuntu 10.4 default version of sun-java6-jre is 1.6.0_20 i want 1.6.0_17

Comment: let me re ask this question apecifically

Comment: @abc, No, in 10.04 the default java isn't from sun, perhaps that's your problem.

Comment: yeah its openJdk, but when i fire apt-get install sun-java6-jre it installs the 1.6.0_20 update by default. i want to downgrade to 1.6.0_17

Comment: sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre=1.6.0_17
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '1.6.0_17' for 'sun-java6-jre' was not found

Comment: As noted in my updated answer, I don't think that version exists for Sun's JRE.